# Place Sub-Div in New Parent for Mobile/Narrow Width, 3-Col Bootstrap Otherwise

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lukeu3f8/4/

I have a 3-Column Boostrap layout. Selecting something in Col 1 activates 2, then 2 activates 3 (like a step-by-step Wizard).

The issue is **when the browser is resized (and in Mobile) Columns 2 and 3 wrap around Column 1 at the bottom**. You can see this if you resize the JSFiddle window.

Initially when the page is opened, this is no big deal because no selection has been made. It's OK to show 1,2,3 sequentially in a single column. But once a Col 1 menu is selected, in mobile (or desktop if `$(window).width() < 1000`  in my experience) **Col 2 and later Col 3 must be detached/prepended under the MenuItem LI (in front)** that was clicked. I also think I have to scroll to the active LI, but that can come later. All other scenarios are OK, we can keep the 3-col layout as it is.

I probably need a function both on startup and resizing that does something like

```
    function resizeSec2And3() {

        var limit = 1000;
        // Only perform the detachment if (1) window width < limit, (2) menu selection has been made
        if ($(window).width() < limit && currmenuitemindex != -1) {
            var col2element = $('#divCol2').detach();
            // Append DIV to the clicked LI
            // ...
        }

    }
```

But I'm not getting the index of the clicked LI, any quick thoughts on indexing and how to attach the resize event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not getting the index of the clicked LI, any quick thoughts on indexing

I would add classes (e.g. `menu-item-1`) or data attributes (e.g. `data-index="1"`) to the `<li>` elements. It's easy if you generate your menu using JS. (Otherwise you can iterate over existing list items too and do the same.)

```js
var items = [
  'Menu item 1', 
  'Menu item 2', 
  'Menu item 3'
];

$(function(){
  $.each(items, function(i, e) {
     $('#menu').append('<li data-index="'+i+'">'+e+'</li>');
  });
  $('#menu > li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('index'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click on items</h1>
<ul id="menu"></ul>
```

> and how to attach the resize event?

You can [attach event handler for the onResize](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp) event by assigning a function to `window.onresize` or by calling `window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction)`. For example:

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1000) {
    $('#mode').text('mobile');
  } else {
    $('#mode').text('desktop');
  }
};
window.onresize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="mode"></h1>
```

And you can add/remove classes to/from your lists depending on the current screen width.

I would also try to use Bootstrap's magic classes like `hidden-BREAKPOINT` and `visible-BREAKPOINT`, that way the resize event may not needed. See the below example, where there's a nested list on smaller screens and two lists on larger ones:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Menu 1</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1/1
          <ul class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <li>Item 2/1</li>
            <li>Item 2/2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 1/2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
      <h1>Menu 2</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 2/1</li>
        <li>Item 2/2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope I could help.